# Excel VBA - UserForm ListBox Not Populating

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox added to a userform. When I set a property, add an item, etc. via code, nothing appears in the listbox. I don't get an error, the listbox just remains blank. 
Here's a snippet. I reviewed the listbox properties and Enabled and Visible are true, Locked is false.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
ListBox1.Clear
Dim wb As Workbook
UserForm1.ListBox1.BackColor = RGB(5, 5, 5) 'threw this in for testing; box not changed
For Each wb In Workbooks
   MsgBox wb.Name
   ListBox1.AddItem wb.Name 
   'this is what I'm trying to accomplish; 
   'wb.Name shows in the MsgBox but not in the listbox
Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: this code is inside the userform? change `userform1.BackColor` to `me.BackColor`

Answer (score 2):

The code has no errors and works, but i had to change the fore-color of the listbox in order to see the item

Comment: What did you change the ForeColor property to?

Comment: simply to white, because this line UserForm1.ListBox1.BackColor = RGB(5, 5, 5) tured the Listbox into black (nearly)

Comment: I just can't get this to work. I deleted the listbox and added a new one and still no luck. Here's the current code:

Comment: Private Sub Refresh_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Workbooks
   ListBox1.AddItem wb.Name
Next wb
End Sub

Comment: sorry, i have no idea, i created a Userform1, perform the load ans show stuff and executed your code without any problems...

Comment: I think I figured it out. The form was inside a Frame. Although I could address the Form directly (i.e., without having "Frame1" in the dot hierarchy, and although I didn't get any errors, ListBox1 won't populate. I moved the objects out of the Frame and deleted it, and then ListBox1 populated correctly. Thank you for your help on this!